# Overriding CALayer's initWithLayer in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, calayer

I'm learning how to use CALayers and perform animations on their properties. To a beginner Apple's documentation is simply cryptic. I managed to find an example (called: CustomAnimatableProperty) in iOS's documentation which somewhat 'explains' how to do what I want:

```
// For CALayer subclasses, always support initWithLayer: by copying over custom properties.
-(id)initWithLayer:(id)layer {
    if( ( self = [super initWithLayer:layer] ) ) {
        if ([layer isKindOfClass:[BulbLayer class]]) {
            self.brightness = ((BulbLayer*)layer).brightness;
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Translating the method override to Swift however gives me a few errors:
[image]

The errors stem from my lacking understanding of what's going on here. I'm not sure what are we checking for in those nested if statements. Also I am a bit baffled by the usage of "=" in the main if(){} block. Shouldn't we be checking ("==") for equality?

But yeah any general help would mean the world. I've tried reviewing a few blog-posts / tutorials online, however non of them deals with this speciffic issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `self = [super init...]` idiom is for Objective-C, not Swift.  In Swift, `init` blocks aren't normal functions and don't return anything.

While we're at it, let's use the Swift idiom for downcasting.  We also need to guarantee that `size` is initialized before we call `super.init`.

```
override init(layer: AnyObject!) {
    if let layer = layer as? SegmentActiveLayer {
        size = layer.size
    } else {
        size = 0
    }
    super.init(layer: layer)
}
```